# Why is function main required and println not working

Tags: kotlin

I am learning how to use Kotlin by doing tests online here: https://pl.kotl.in/P-v2WU7SH
My code I'm testing is:

```kt
fun main() {
}

fun test(a: Int): Int{
    var c: Int = a*2
    return c
}

var z: Int = 5
var k: Int = test(z)
println(k)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does `println(k)` show me the error ("Expecting a top level declaration") and when I remove it I have no problem?
2. Why when I delete `fun main(){}` and run my code it displays: "No main method found in project"?

Answer (score 1):

Many old tutorials don't work with new versions of Kotlin. In this case, you seem to be writing a Kotlin script, whereas the compiler/IDE is likely recognizing the file as a class.

To make Kotlin scripts work on Kotlin 1.4, make the following changes:

Add this to `build.gradle`

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm")
```

And rename your script file from `.kt` to `.kts`.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin's still bound by the same JVM rules as Java.

- All code is initialized and run from a main method.
- No methods can be called outside the context of any method.

So, if you put your variable declarations and your `println` statement into `main`, it'd work fine.

Comment: While this answers the question of the OP, it’s not entirely true: Kotlin script does away with the need for a `main()` function and can run top-level `println()` easily. Just rename your file to `*.kts` instead of simle `.kt`.